# Poor low frequency response of CD4060 IC

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, counter, timing, ripple-counter

I have a question that involves a CD4060 ripple counter.

My project is to design a counting circuit that turns off a relay after two hours. This can be done simply using an Arduino, but no microprocessors can be included.

I am using a CD4060 ripple counter with an RC oscillator (I attached an image of the configuration). The output starts deviating from the (expected; I'm assuming) square wave and starts resembling a capacitor discharge at stage 10 and gets worse every stage after.

So here are my questions:

1. The capacitor I'm using is a monolithic multilayer ceramic chip cap, is this an appropriate type of capacitor to use as a timing cap?
2. I have seen multiple equations for calculating the oscillation frequency throughout the web. Overall, it's \$1/[(2.x)*(C)*(R)]\$. The first quantity is labeled 2.x because I have seen 2.2, 2.3, and 2.5 ... so I am wondering which of these numbers it actually is?
3. I have read that the deviation from the square wave is due to a poor low frequency response. Can this be confirmed? Are there any possible remedies for this issue?

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: How are you measuring it? With an oscilloscope? Is the channel input AC or DC coupled? What frequency is coming out of stage 10?

Comment: 1) Do you have a ceramic decoupling cap from Vdd to ground near the IC? The 47 uF is fairly useless at high frequencies. 2) The datasheet that I found on Digikey recommends that R2 be 2 to 10 times R1, you have exceeded that ratio.

Comment: Switch the scope input to DC ( and not 50 Ohms), calibrate your scope probe, and try again.

Comment: The coupling was set to DC, I am currently calibrating it then will recheck. Thanks all. The 47uF is an electrolytic used as decoupling cap

Comment: The calibration worked, thank you very much! The frequency on stage 10 is 25.38Hz.

Comment: And I apologize!! the 2.2uF is actually a 47pF.

Comment: IMO it's because 10M for R2 is way too much. I don't understand how you get a 2 hours delay if the output at Q10 is 25Hz. Is this only part of the circuit?  I would suggest using an ic including a multi-stage divider. Just at random (may not be the best choice): MC14536B or CD4541B. With this, you use a fast clock pulse with accurate components within recommended range. The pulse will be divided by many thousands (depends how many stages you choose) and give you as a result a two hours delay. Since I'm not sure about the cause of the problem, I  keep it as a comment.